# The cohomology of $S^3/D^*_k$

Tags: algebraic-topology, solution-verification, covering-spaces, quotient-spaces

> I have tried to compute the de Rham cohomology and the homology over the integers  of the space $S^3/D^*_k$, where $D^*_k$ is the binary dihedral group of order $4k$ and I would like to know if what I have done is correct.

If we think of $S^3\subset \mathbb{C}^2$, $S^3=\{(z^1,z^2):|z^1|^2+|z^2|^2=1\}$, the action of $D^*_k$ that I want to consider is generated by 
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
g_1&:(z^1,z^2)\mapsto \mathrm{e}^{\frac{i\,\pi}{k} }(z^1,z^2),\\
g_2&:(z^1,z^2)\mapsto i\,(\bar z ^2,-\bar z ^1).
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Let us start with de Rham cohomology. Since $H^*(S^3/D^*_k)=H^{*\,D^*_k}(S^3)$ and $H^*(S^3)$ is non-vanishing only in degree 0 and 3, we immediately have $H^1(S^3/D^*_k)=H^2(S^3/D^*_k)=0$. Since $S^3/D^*_k$ is connected, $H^0(S^3/D^*_k)=\mathbb{R}$ and by Poincare duality $H^3(S^3/D^*_k)=\mathbb{R}$, hence

> \begin{equation}
> H^p_{\mathrm{dR}}(S^3/D^*_k)=\begin{cases}
> \mathbb{R}&\text{if $p=0,3$,}\\ 0&\text{otherwise}.
> \end{cases}
> \end{equation}

Next I have tried to calculate homology with integer coefficients.
$H_0(S^3/D^*_k)=\mathbb{Z}$ as the space is connected. To calculate $H_1$ I thought of looking at the abelianization of $\pi_1$. Since $S^3$ is the universal cover, $\pi_1(S^3/D^*_k)=D^*k$ which has the presentation
\begin{equation}
D^*_k=\langle x,a:a^{2k}=e,x^2=a^k,xax^{-1}=a^{-1} \rangle.
\end{equation}
Now I am not sure if this is the correct way to calculate the ablianization of a group, but I thought that I can treat the product in the relations as commutative thus getting $a=a^{-1}$, hence $a$ has order 2. Then if $k$ is even $x$ is also of order 2 and the abelianization is $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$, while if $k$ is odd we get $\mathbb{Z}_4$.
Is this correct?

By Poincare duality $H_3(S^3/D^*_k)=H^0(S^3/D^*_k)=\mathbb{Z}$. Hence

> \begin{equation}
> H_p(S^3/D^*_k,\mathbb{Z})=\begin{cases}
> \mathbb{Z}&\text{if $p=0,3$},\\
> \mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2&\text{if $p=1$ and $k$ is even,}\\
> \mathbb{Z}_4&\text{if $p=1$ and $k$ is odd,}\\
> 0 &\text{otherwise}.
> \end{cases}
> \end{equation}

I do not know how to compute $H_2$.

EDIT: I think I have found how to compute $H_2$: Since $S^3/D^*_k$ is compact and orientable $H_2$ has no torsion. Its rank can be found using the fact that $0=\chi(S^3)=|D^*_k|\cdot\chi(S^3/D^*_k)\Rightarrow \chi(S^3/D^*_k)=0$. Since we know the ranks of all the other groups it follows that the rank of $H_2$ is zero.

Comment: Why is your space orientable? Maybe this is obvious but it's not clear to me.

Comment: @MikeMiller One can check that the standard volume form of $S^3$ is invariant under the action of $g_1$, $g_2$ so it descends to $S^3/D^*_k$ which is therefore orientable. Indeed I should have written this explicitly instead of using Poincaré duality which assumes orientability...

Comment: If that's the case then indeed your arguments look correct to me.

Comment: Okie doke, I verified what you said about the volume form, so unless I've made an error of my own this is all correct.

Comment: @MikeMiller Thanks again for your help!